# Setup code for loopback under boot folder

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I'm looking to access control example.  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control

It says we need to put sample-models.js file under server/boot folder. That means, everytime I run the application, the creation process will be made again and again. Of course, I'm getting errors on the second call.

Should I put my own mechanism to disable if ones it run, or is there a functionality in loopback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot scripts are for setting up the application. And run once per application start.

So if you want to initialize database or any initializing which would be persisted by running boot script, you need to check if it is initialized first or not.

For example for initializing roles in db, you need to check if there is desired roles in db or not. And if there is not, so create ones.

There is no other functionality in loopback for this.